# how to find x and y position in tablet resolution and validate with alert message with user input

Tags: javascript

Design a triangle on the screen. sides can be changed using CSS.
User input- X and Y position to place the triangle on the screen size (1024* 768). Validate the user input(X, Y) and if value is higher than screen size, please show Alert message!(Entered value is out of screen!!)

Comment: i am new in js and does not how to solve this. So can any one help me in specially in funcnality part. Thanks.

Comment: please show us what have you tried...

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 2):

***`screen.width` is your screen width such as 1400.***

***`screen.height` is your screen height such as 900.***

Use this:

```js
function changePosition(){
  let x=document.getElementById('x').value;
  let y=document.getElementById('y').value;
  if(x>screen.width || y>screen.height){
    alert('Error: Wrong input!!');
    return false; // stop running code
  }
  let triangle=document.getElementById('triangle');
  triangle.style.left=x+'px';
  triangle.style.top=y+'px';
}
```

```css
div.triangle{
  position:absolute; /* free to change element position in screen. */
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle" class="triangle"></div>
<input id="x" placeholder="x" type="number">
<input id="y" placeholder="y" type="number">
<input type="button" onclick="changePosition();" value="change pos">
```

Comment: Thanks sir a lot. You have saved my lot of time and efforts. It helps me very well. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, Please accept answer to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, one has to know the difference between `screen`, `window`, `document`, and `viewport`. Each provide a different width/height. I'll break them down briefly.

- Screen: The actual physical screen of your device.

  - `window.screen.width or window.screen.height`: The actual screen size i.e. full screen size of your device's display. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)
- Window: The whole browser window. Its width/height includes the menubar, bookmarksbar, etc. and viewport.

  - `window.outerWidth or window.outerHeight`: The size of browser. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth)
- Viewport: It is the rectangle area where things are visible to you i.e part of the webpage you're viewing which is currently visible.

  - `window.innerWidth or window.innerHeight`: returns width/height (in pixels) including scrollbar and borders. Hence probably the size you need. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)
  - `x.clientWidth or x.clientHeight`: e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].clientWidth` will return width/height minus the scrollbar, borders, and margins. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)
- Document: The whole webpage. Its width/height can exceed the viewport/window i.e. scrolling vertically/horizontally to see the rest of document on viewport.

  - Depreciated (can't use) `window.document.width` [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/width)

So having read and understood all this, you can decide which one to use.